# How to call function in custom js

Tags: magento2

How can call the _isPcDev in the addManuallyArrayfunction function.

`this._isPcDev` or `this._isPcDev()` not working

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried to call the _isPcDev() directly without the "this."?

Comment: I tried this```_isPcDev```or```_isPcDev()``` tell me ```lzy-assets.js:204 Uncaught ReferenceError: _isPcDev is not defined```It still doesn't work